# Check if displayed string is truncated using spy++

Tags: c#, ui-automation, spy++

I am currently testing a .msi application wherein I use spy++ to extract the strings from the application and verify those strings against strings I already have defined and then I log the mismatches using C#. I've encountered a scenario where if the string is too long, the application truncates it with ellipses "..." . However when I extract the string from the applicaiton using spy++ I get the entire un-truncated string. Is there a way, where I can find out if the string is truncated in the application using spy++ or UIAutomation elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As truncation is part of UI display, It is just falling short of displaying a long string. But while fetching, you will get the complete string. So It may not be possible to find if the string is truncated or not.